# Issues with creating a tcl package in same directory as other source tcl files

Tags: package, tcl, tk-toolkit

I started learning tcl a few days ago and am currently trying to create a simple password manager gui application. I created two toplevel windows using tcl/tk in separate files than I intend to call from a main tcl file using the source command. I decided to split up the other tcl functions that handled hashing; checking hashes; and file IO in another tcl file. Then I would bind these functions to the gui widgets by "importing the function file". I wanted to import the assorted tcl functions from the same directory as the other tcl file containing the gui code, much like python's import system. However I have experienced differculty creating a package, I have looked up as many guides as I can find and am still confused about the process. I created a namespace in the functions file then added a provided line, then ran pkg_mkIndex . *.tcl in the tclsh shell. Then I added requires function file to the gui widget file and put the lappend auto_path command at the top of the file. However as soon as I run the file I get an annoying can't find package popup. Note: I am using a tcl interperter on windows. Any help would be greatly apperciated and also I am relatively new to programming and tcl in general so any other tips would also be helpful. Thanks in advance!

**widget file contains this at header**

```
lappend auto_path "C:\Users\j715c\coding_projects\tcl\tcl_proj\password_manager"
package require  FileHandler
```

**Function File contains this**

```
package provide FileHandler $FileHandler::version
package require Tcl 8.5
package require sha256

namespace eval ::FileHandler {
 
  
  namespace export check_password_attempt load_file check_null_file check_hash hash write_file parse_entries
  set version 1.0
  set hashedpass ""
 
}
```

[full code here on github](https://github.com/crabster15/SimplePassWord)

Comment: Use `variable` to define those namespace variables, not `set` (because otherwise you can have [“fun”](https://dwarffortresswiki.org/index.php?title=DF2014:Fun&redirect=no) with variable resolvers). I also prefer to put the `package provide` right at the end of my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to generate the `pkgIndex.tcl` file, I get this error:

```sh
$ echo 'pkg_mkIndex -verbose . *.tcl' | tclsh
warning: error while sourcing FileHandler.tcl: can't read "FileHandler::version": no such variable
```

You're using the version variable before it's defined. Don't forget that Tcl is an interpreted language.

Try this:

```
namespace eval ::FileHandler { variable version 1.0 }

package provide FileHandler $FileHandler::version
package require Tcl 8.5-
package require sha256

namespace eval ::FileHandler {
  namespace export check_password_attempt load_file check_null_file check_hash hash write_file parse_entries
  variable hashedpass ""
}
```

Note the required Tcl version ends with `-` so that Tcl 8.6 can be used.

Now,

```sh
$ echo 'pkg_mkIndex -verbose . *.tcl' | tclsh
successful sourcing of FileHandler.tcl
packages provided were {FileHandler 1.0}
processed FileHandler.tcl

$ cat pkgIndex.tcl
# comments ...
package ifneeded FileHandler 1.0 [list source [file join $dir FileHandler.tcl]]

$ tclsh
% lappend auto_path .
% package req FileHandler
1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I didn't know that their was a verbose flag for pkg_mkIndex, that is very helpful for debugging.